# Alternative to angular2 i18n

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm looking for a convenient way to use angular2's built in i18n support, in order to handle server side messages returned by an API. For example, I have a big dynamic menu, with labels for each item that comes from the server. I also have messages (errors, warnings, result codes) coming from the API.

Since I've found issues that I consider blocking [like this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11405), I'm  also looking for a 3rd party library that allows simple key/value translation messages and can be included in an angular2 app. I'm new in Angular2 so I would like to hear about community accepted libraries for this case.

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core

Comment: Thanks @developer033 that was the library I was looking for, post it as answer if you want.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm looking for a library that allows simple key/value translation messages and can be included in an angular2 app.

It is quite easy to write:

```
type Messages = {
  error: string,
  hello: string,
}

export function getMessage(message: keyof Messages, localization = 'en') {
  /** Define your messages */
  const messages: {
    [localization: string]: Messages;
  } = {
      en: {
        error: 'Unexpected error',
        hello: 'hello world'
      }
    }
  return messages[localization][message];
}

// Usage 
getMessage('error'); // OK
getMessage('notvalid'); // Compile time error
```

You can expand this pattern to be as powerful as *you need it to be*

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the answer you are looking for, but I just want to document that it is trivial to provide message values for server errors using Angular's static translations.

```
@Component(
  template: `
    <ng-container [ngSwitch]="errorCode">
      <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="error1" i18n>A bad thing happend</ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="5152" i18n>Error in AE35 unit</ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngSwitchCaseDefault i18n>Unknown Error</ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  `
)
export class ErrorMessageComponent {
  @Input errorCode: number | string;
}
```